# Can’t select operative system at startup after repairing with boot-repair

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, boot-repair

I have a laptop with windows 10, which I partitioned and installed Ubuntu 16.04. At startup I was able to choose Ubuntu and Windows 10, being Linux the first option. After the latest Windows 10 update I got this error:

```
no such partition. Entering rescue mode… 
grub rescue>
```

I used a usb to start an Ubuntu env and boot-repair with the default option to repair the MBR, as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Now the computer starts Windows 10 directly, without allowing me to choose the OS. What can I do to select the OS again?

Answer (score 0):

I think almost certainly Windows has installed its own bootloader during a windows update, very annoying. I guess you are using EUFI and not BIOS, I confess to setting my machines to legacy BIOS because I am more familiar with it. I dual boot multiple linux OS and have re installed grub on many occassions and I know how it works with BIOS and MBR partitions.

In my scenario, if I wanted to re install the  grub bootloader to the MBR and have it store the config on partition 3 it would be

boot from an Ubuntu CD

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt

sudo grub-install /dev/sda --boot-directory=/mnt/boot

sudo umount /mnt
```

Reboot

Really not sure if EUFI is works with grub in a totally different way but I offer this info as a possible starting point.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. The problem was related to the sector size that was used when originally installing the ubuntu OS. Using testdisk solved the problem.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer and exactly how you resolved the issue so others can benefit ?